# Nilpotent Localization in Group Theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory

Algebraic topologists have invented a very pretty technique of localizing nilpotent groups.  (Garth Warner covers the topic in his book manuscript [Topics in Topology and Homotopy Theory](http://www.math.washington.edu/~warner/)).  For topologists this construction is a means to an end, but I'm curious if it has any pure group-theoretic applications.  Are there any theorems about nilpotent groups that have been proven using the technique?  Are there any pre-existing theorems which are best understood from the point of view of localization?

Comment: I think, the ideas of localization go back to Malcev's work (in 1949) on Malcev completion, http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Mal%27cev+completion, which is a basic tool in studying finitely generated nilpotent groups. I suspect that whatever can be learned about nilpotent groups via localization, can be seen by analysing the Malcev completion.

Comment: As a mathscinet search (on nilpotent group and localization) reveals, there are lots of group theoretic application. I was unable to find any recent survey though.